# How to detect if System.Web.Mvc.dll is installed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, dll

I have a class library that provides me some shared functionality for `WebForm`, `MVC`, `WinForm`, and `WPF` applications. There is just one `class` that uses a type placed in *`System.Web.Mvc.dll`*. While `System.Web.Mvc` is not a main part of *`.NET`*, some enironments may dont have it. e.g. this class library may be used in a `WPF` application, or in a `MVC` application.

What I need is to check if *`System.Web.Mvc.dll`* is available or not. If yep, then create my `System.Web.Mvc` depended class dynamically, otherwise ignore this part of code. Is there any way to detect if *`System.Web.Mvc.dll`* is installed on a system or is enabled in an enviorenment? And if yes, how can I detect its version?

Comment: Can't you ship it with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create instenace of your class (or better some class from System.Web.Mvc.dll) and catch appropriate exception. Be careful not to have static members of types that may not be present as detection will be trickier as static constructors are called "before" object is needed (where "before" does not have strict place in code execution).

You aslo may be able to simply carry the DLL with your DLL (please to double check license).